# posting requires a permission login dialog to appear twice

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-login, facebook-authorization

I am developing a mobile camera app that allows posting a photo on facebook. The camera app is a stand-alone and does not require facebook login when it starts. However I want to allow posting a picture to facebook. It follows that the first time a user will try uploading an image it will have to go through the permission login dialog twice.

I cant find a way to ask the user for access his basic information + posting of an image on his wall with one login dialog.

This seems "by design" if you read: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/

Its a bad users experience to be transfered in and out the mobile app twice in a row to allow posting.

Is there a way to ask the user for basic information + posting of an image in one pass?

Comment: Solve it ....if not then comment please ...

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps :

1) Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2) Click on your app.
3) Click edit app
4) Click Advanced
5) Check Enhanced Auth Dialog: Disabled

That's it. You have one authentication popup.

You get two pop-ups because one of them is a basic permission popup for the app while the other popup asks for extended permissions i.e. publish_stream to post a photo on behalf of the user. For more info on facebook permissions, go to : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/

Comment: I am coming from a developer stand-point. I want to avoid as much hassle as possible to the users of my app. I understand the publish_stream must be another popup but why is it taking me to the facebook app on the phone for the basic auth, then back to my app, then back to the facebook app for the publish_stream..  There should be a way to tell the API i want to switch to the facebook app just once and then approve both auths.. right ?

Comment: had the same problem and your suggestion worked for me. funny, I didn't have extended permissions and fb andrid sdk 3.5.2 showed two popups back to back anyways..

Comment: Unable to find Enhanced Auth Dialog any where in Advanced settings

Answer (score 0):

@Oriel Bergig Facebook update the sdk.
(v3.0.1 as of March 20, 2013. See what's new in 3.0.). Download from this link .

https://developers.facebook.com/android/

Follow the link 
Problem is solved .If any issue ping me.

Comment: How to resolve this issue.Login dialog open twice for facebook