# Facebook login on android: Clicking twice on login button yields an error

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I have an Android application that requires a Facebook login. When one tries to log in via Facebook, entering login and password, clicking twice on the "Log In" button will yield the following error:

> The page you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be
>   temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may be broken or
>   expired, or you may not have permission to view this page.

My questions are:

- Did anyone else encounter this error?
- What causes this?
- Any idea how to solve this on my application side?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you login if you only click once? are you sure you have set up your key hashes correctly (and waited patiently for it to change)?

Comment: I can login if I click once

Comment: Follow the link I share  view.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943128/posting-requires-a-permission-login-dialog-to-appear-twice/15811120#15811120